# Showing a Belongs_To relation in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question involving the belongs_to relationship. Currently, I have a Item which belongs_to a Name. This name has a title which is the title of the Item. In the view, it displays

```
<% = item.name.title %>
```

which consistently comes up with an error message that the "title method" does not exist, despite the fact that it is not a method. Suggestions?

Comment: I am not able to see the code...

Answer (score 0):

Properties are methods that are funneled through ActiveRecord::Base and accessed as methods.  You can see the code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb).

I would guess your item doesn't have a name associated with it, but it would still have the name method.  If you output item.name, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This will error if your title object does not have a name object attached. One way to fix this is to use this instead:

```
<% if item.name %>
  <%= item.name.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fearing that the problem is much deeper than you think.

> a Item which belongs_to a Name

Okay, you surely meant that an `Item has_one :name` and a `Name belongs_to :item`.
Can't you just add a column `:name` to your table `items` ?

> This name has a title which is the title of the Item

Oulala. Do you mean `item.title == item.name.title` ?

> In the view, it displays <% = item.name.title %> which consistently comes up with an error

Ok. It doesn't display anything in the view then.

> an error message that the "title method" does not exist, despite the fact that it is not a method

If it's not a method, what is it?
What does say the error message exactly?